# Roundcube mail , User A send mail to wrong person User C, any way to delete that specific mail , since can't recall mail

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, roundcube

Roundcube mail

OS       : Centos 8
Database : MSSQL

User A send mail to wrong person User C, the mail should be meant to send to User B. Any way to delete that specific mail ?

since roundcube had no recall feature or any plug that support undo send. although there pay feature plugin available for undo send. however was wandering anyone out there had any method or way to delete specific mail or message.

Comment: No, not unless you have access to the recipient's mail server. Otherwise, in general, this is not possible.